# Mounting a partclone image

Tags: mount

I'm having a really strange issue.

I have backups of my machine in a local RAID array. They were created by Clonezilla, so I've created an actual filesystem image like so:

```
cat 2013-11-29/sda3.btrfs-ptcl-img.gz.* | gzip -d -c | \
    partclone.restore -C -s - -O 2013-11-29.sda3.img
```

This has created a nice big image file in the current directory.

However, when I go to mount it, I've noticed that it doesn't actually mount the image file; it simply creates a loop to `/`:

```
$ sudo mount 2013-11-29.sda3.img /mnt
```

To test this, I've created a simple file that shouldn't exist in the backup.

```
$ ls /home/naftuli | grep "newfile"
$ ls /mnt/home/naftuli | grep "newfile"
$ touch ~/newfile
```

I would expect that now, `/home/naftuli/newfile` exists, but `/mnt/home/naftuli/newfile` does *not* exist. However, it is apparent that the mount is looping to `/`, as the `newfile` exists in *both* places:

```
$ ls /home/naftuli | grep "newfile"
newfile
$ ls /mnt/home/naftuli | grep "newfile"
newfile
```

How can I force `mount` to mount the image file and specifically not loop to `/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to an implementation specific issue, I was unable to mount the image in the end.

On BTRFS, filesystem UUIDs need to be unique. When I tried mounting my partclone image, Linux would see that a device with the same image was already mounted at `/`, and therefore would simply loop back to that device. There isn't really a workaround, as BTRFS stores UUID information in every block and there isn't a way to simply ignore the UUID during mount.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to provide the `-o loop` switch to mount these `.img` files.

#### Example

```
$ sudo mount -o loop 2013-11-29.sda3.img /mnt
```

You might need to provide the `-t` switch too, to `mount`. This switch tells mount the type of filesystem you're attempting to mount.

```
$ sudo mount -o loop -t ext3 2013-11-29.sda3.img /mnt
```

See the section in the `mount` man page, that covers loop devices.

#### References

- [How to: Mount an ISO image under Linux](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-mount-iso-image-under-linux.html)
- [8.8. Mounting a disk image using the loop device](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/loop-device-usage.html)
- [mount(8) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)

Comment: It's _still_ binding to `/` and not mounting the archive. If the volume id of the image file is the same as `/`, could that be the reason it won't use the image file, as it thinks its already mounted?

Comment: I'm really thinking that mount is seeing that the volume ids of `2013-11-29.sda3.img` and `/` are the same and is refusing to "remount" the image and simply looping back to `/`.