# mount complains about exFAT when mounting partclone image of NTFS partition

Tags: mount, partclone

I've made a backup of an NTFS partition with partclone, like this:

```
partclone.ntfs -cs /dev/sdk1  -o ./ntfs_backup.img
```

In case that's relevant: The physical hard drive was sitting in a USB dock.

Now, I'd like to compare the contents of that image with the contents of the partition, which have changed in the meantime. To do that, I've put the hard drive in the USB dock again, and it shows up alright as having 4 NTFS partition, and nothing else.
Then, I am trying to mount the image with the original state of that partition, but that fails:

```
# mount ./ntfs_backup.img /mnt/ntfs_backup
FUSE exfat 1.3.0
ERROR: exFAT file system is not found.
```

Why on earth is exFAT being mentioned here?
I read through [this question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103959/mounting-a-partclone-image) and tried using the `-o loop` option, but that changes nothing. I also tried specifying the file system type explicitly:

```
# mount -t ntfs ./ntfs_backup.img /mnt/ntfs_backup
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/loop10': Das Argument ist ungültig
The device '/dev/loop10' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Looking closer, however, it seems that partclone images are not directly mountable, even though I did not compress this one (because I wanted to be able to mount it directly). According to a [few](https://www.tonmann.com/2015/07/03/how-to-temporary-mount-clonezilla-images-to-restore-single-files-or-folders/) [other](https://blog.christosoft.de/2012/05/mount-clonezilla-image-to-restore-single-file-browse/) resources, I should be using `partclone.restore` to convert the cloned image file to a ... regular image file?

However:

```
# cat ./ntfs_backup.img | partclone.restore -C -s - -O ./ntfs_backup.img
Partclone v0.3.13 http://partclone.org
Starting to restore image (-) to device (./ntfs_backup_mountable.img)
device (./ntfs_backup_mountable.img) is mounted at 
error exit
Partclone fail, please check /var/log/partclone.log !
```

I suppose I can skip the piping here because the image is not compressed, but running `partclone.restore -C -s ./ntfs_backup.img -o ntfs_backup.img` gives me the same error.

...what am I doing wrong?

For this time, I do need to mount the image (which I also have as a n fsarchive file, in case that helps at all), but for the future, I wouldn't mind knowing how to create a mountable image of a partition directly.

**Update**
Following some advice from @kanehekili used `ntfs-3g` to specify the file system type:

```
# mount -t ntfs-3g ./ntfs_backup.img /mnt/ntfs_backup
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount './ntfs_backup.img': Das Argument ist ungültig
The device '/ntfs_backup.img' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

So, interestingly, this no longer tries to refer to `/dev/loop10`. I don't know what to make of it, though.

I think I must be misunderstanding something, or the way I created the images is not compatible with the mounting process. I *was* able to clone the image back onto another hard drive without problems, though, using `partclone.ntfs`.

This means the immediate problem is solved, but I'd still like to be able to create an image of a partition (using partclone -- or fsarchiver) which can be mounted, at least read-only.

Comment: what does `file ntfs_backup.img` return?

Comment: @Artem S. Tashkinov: ``ntfs_backup.img: data`` -- what does this tell me?

Answer (score 1):

since you've got an NTFS file system the mount should be executed with:

`mount -t ntfs-3g`

otherwise mount will try to find some way to do it... which happens to be exFAT

--- Edit ---
Since the OP couldn't extract the image, the question is, whether partclone creates a original ntfs image. It would be worth a try to use `dd`for it:

```
dd bs=4M if=/dev/sdK1 of= ntfsbackup.image status=progress oflag=sync
```

Someone uses [ntfsclone](https://uriesk.wordpress.com/2015/09/27/backup-ntfs-partition-from-within-linux/) - it may be worth a try...

Comment: Thanks! That certainly corrected one mistake -- but as described in the updated question, it did not solve the issue, unfortunately...

Comment: According to the error message, that img is not ntfs. Question is what partclone does. A real image or only some kind of proprietary  backup image. Then only partclone could restore it. If you would use the `dd` command to clone that partion, it should work (See my updated answer)